# Как правильно занести данные в таблицу, спарсенные c помощью PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Пытаюсь спарсить элементы со страницы и разместить их в таблицу. Использую PHP Simple Html Dom Parser.

Парсит нормально, но как только пытаюсь вывести в таблицу, то названия статей зацикливаются, и выводится одно и то же название только последней статьи напротив спарсенных просмотров и комментариев.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вывести название каждой статьи напротив соответствующего ей количества просмотров.

Спасибо.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Статья</th>
      <th>Количество просмотров/комментариев</th>
    </tr>
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://site_name');

foreach($html->find('h3.publ_title') as $b) {
}
foreach($html->find('.publication_buttons') as $a) {
echo "<tr><td>$b->plaintext</td><td>$a</td></tr>";
}
?>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как есть

```
// Получили html
$html = file_get_html('http://baltluch.ru/ecotropa47');

// Пробежались пустым циклом по всем заголовкам
foreach($html->find('h3.publ_title') as $b) {
}
// Теперь $b содержит заголовок последней статьи

// Пробежались по всем статистическим данным
foreach($html->find('.publication_buttons') as $a) {
  // вывели заголовок последней статьи и статистику текущей статьи
  echo "<tr><td>$b->plaintext</td><td>$a</td></tr>";
}
```

Как должно быть

```
// Получили html
$html = file_get_html('http://baltluch.ru/ecotropa47');

// Пробежались циклом по всем статьям
foreach($html->find('div.publication') as $pub) {
  // Получили заголовок текущей статьи
  $title = $pub->find('h3.publ_title', 0);
  // Получили статистику текущей статьи
  $stat = $pub->find('.publication_buttons', 0);
  // вывели информацию
  echo "<tr><td>$title->plaintext</td><td>$stat</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но не сработало - теперь просто выводит массив (добавил в результат). Но логика ясна, буду думать! Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Gusar Я исправил ответ